# NLTK tag Dutch sentence

Tags: python, nltk

I am beginning with NLTK and want to tag a Dutch sentence but I am having trouble specifying the corpus.

```
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import alpino

pos_tag(word_tokenize("Python is een goede data science taal."), tagset = 'alpino')
```

gives,

```
[('Python', 'UNK'),
 ('is', 'UNK'),
 ('een', 'UNK'),
 ('goede', 'UNK'),
 ('data', 'UNK'),
 ('science', 'UNK'),
 ('taal', 'UNK'),
 ('.', 'UNK')]
```

So clearly I am not specifying the corpus correctly. I downloaded the alpino corpus. Can anyone help me to figure out how to specify the corpus correctly?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732465/nltk-tagging-spanish-words-using-a-corpus and https://github.com/alvations/spaghetti-tagger

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default `nltk.pos_tag` was trained for English text, you would have to train a new tagger on the `alpino` corpus to roll your own Dutch tagger.

But note that the model will be as good as:

- what data it is trained on
- which algorithm it is trained with

From `UnigramTagger` and `BigramTagger` example:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import alpino as alp
>>> from nltk.tag import UnigramTagger, BigramTagger
>>> training_corpus = alp.tagged_sents()
>>> unitagger = UnigramTagger(training_corpus)
>>> bitagger = BigramTagger(training_corpus, backoff=unitagger)
>>> pos_tag = bitagger.tag
>>> sent = 'NLTK is een goeda taal voor NLP'.split()
>>> pos_tag(sent)
[('NLTK', None), ('is', u'verb'), ('een', u'det'), ('goeda', None), ('taal', u'noun'), ('voor', u'prep'), ('NLP', None)]
```

With `PerceptronTagger`:

```
>>> from nltk.tag import PerceptronTagger
>>> from nltk.corpus import alpino as alp
>>> training_corpus = list(alp.tagged_sents()) 
>>> tagger = PerceptronTagger(load=True)
>>> tagger.train(training_corpus)
>>> sent = 'NLTK is een goeda taal voor het leren over NLP'.split()
>>> tagger.tag(sent)
[('NLTK', u'noun'), ('is', u'verb'), ('een', u'det'), ('goeda', u'adj'), ('taal', u'noun'), ('voor', u'prep'), ('het', u'det'), ('leren', u'noun'), ('over', u'prep'), ('NLP', u'noun')
```

As @WasiAhmed noted, this is another good example: https://github.com/evanmiltenburg/Dutch-tagger and as @evanmiltenburg stated on the github, try to use a faster taggger in production.

---

## EDITED

To evaluate a tagger, you can hold out a `test_set` as such:

```
>>> from nltk.tag import PerceptronTagger
>>> from nltk.corpus import alpino as alp
>>> alp_tagged_sents = list(alp.tagged_sents())
>>> len(alp_tagged_sents)
7136
>>> last_train_sent = int(len(alp_tagged_sents) / 10 * 9)
>>> train_set = alp_tagged_sents[:last_train_sent]
>>> test_set = alp_tagged_sents[last_train_sent:]
```

Then use the `tagger.evaluate()` function to get the accuracy, the input for the `.evaluate()` function is the same as the input for the `.train()` function, i.e. a list of sentence, and each sentence is a list of `('word', 'tag')` tuples:

```
>>> tagger = PerceptronTagger(load=False)
>>> tagger.train(train_set)
>>> tagger.evaluate(test_set)
0.927672285043738
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete example!

Comment: Please extend your answer to show how to evaluate the resulting tagger (with held-out data). The alpino corpus is tiny, so you're not going to get great performance. Don't just train a tagger and use it with your eyes closed!

Comment: @alexis, it's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144473/do-we-need-to-use-stopwords-filtering-before-pos-tagging/40167059#40167059 again. But sure, i'll add to the answer =)

Comment: Well, I wasn't going to point this out, but if the question is a duplicate you should be closing it (and maybe updating your earlier answer), not giving an incomplete answer here.

Comment: Added the eval ;P

Answer (score 4):

You can use this tagger (https://github.com/evanmiltenburg/Dutch-tagger) to tag dutch sentences. The accuracy is 97%.

**Example** (Using `PerceptronTagger`)

```
from nltk.tag.perceptron import PerceptronTagger

# This may take a few minutes. (But once loaded, the tagger is really fast!)
tagger = PerceptronTagger(load=False)
tagger.load('model.perc.dutch_tagger_small.pickle')

# Tag a sentence.
tagger.tag('Alle vogels zijn nesten begonnen , behalve ik en jij .'.split())
```

Output

```
[('Alle', 'det__indef'), ('vogels', 'nounpl'), ('zijn', 'verbprespl'), ('nesten', 'nounpl'), ('begonnen', 'verbpapa'), (',', 'punc'), ('behalve', 'conjsubo'), ('ik', 'pronpers'), ('en', 'conjcoord'), ('jij', 'pronpers'), ('.', '$.')]
```

Comment: Downvote: This doesn't explain what was wrong in the OP's attempt or how to fix it.

Comment: I have also suggested to use the perceptron tagger as suggested in the accepted answer. Sorry if you think it was not helpful.

Comment: I think what @tripleee meant was that the link is helpful but an answer on Stackoverflow shouldn't be link only. It needs a little more explanation so that it helps the OP (original poster of the question).

Comment: To avoid downvotes you must add your opinion instead of just mentioning a random links. Sometimes links just expires or get changed, so people will no longer find the answer.

Comment: @rakeb.mazharul it was not a random link but in future i will keep your suggestion in mind.