# Is there a minimum data size required for BigramTagger to work?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am learning the BigramTagger class in the nltk library. I train a 'Part-of-Sentence' tagger using the brown corpus that comes with nltk.

I notice that if I train on this corpus, and then tag a few words from the first sentence of the corpus, it works great.

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
from nltk.tag import BigramTagger 
from nltk import word_tokenize

# Works completely fine:
brown_train = brown.tagged_sents(categories='news')
bigram_tagger = BigramTagger(brown_train)
print(bigram_tagger.tag(word_tokenize("that any irregularities took place")))
```

We get the expected output:

> [('that', 'CS'), ('any', 'DTI'), ('irregularities', 'NNS'), ('took', 'VBD'), ('place', 'NN')]

But if I only train with 100 sentences, it fails.

```
# Fails to work: 
brown_train = brown.tagged_sents(categories='news')[:100]
bigram_tagger = BigramTagger(brown_train)
print(bigram_tagger.tag(word_tokenize("that any irregularities took place")))
```

It fails to tag these words, so it gives them the None tag:

> [('that', None), ('any', None), ('irregularities', None), ('took', None), ('place', None)]

Is there a minimum corpus required by the class? Or is there some other parameter I am forgetting that makes the model fail in the second case?

I've looked at the documentation here: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#nltk.tag.sequential.BigramTagger and it looks like there is a cutoff parameter, but that is set to 0 by default.

Comment: Usually, the bigram tagger needs the unigram for it to work, see https://github.com/alvations/spaghetti-tagger/blob/master/spaghetti.py#L24

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40212895/610569

Comment: What I'm pointing out here is an inconsistency where my model works when trained on a large dataset, yet fails when trained on a subset, and it is not clear why.

Comment: Interesting, actually this is a very good question! Will get to answering it later when free.

Comment: @alvas I would love if you could give a shot at answering this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting question. It *looks* like you're testing your taggers with the training data, but there's a crucial difference: Since you are using _a fragment* of the first sentence, its first word is presented in a context different from how it was used in training. The short answer to your question is that it's not corpus size, it's just whether the relevant context was seen in training. **With the shorter training data, the first word has never been seen in the same (sentence-initial) position;** but with the long dataset, it has.

Now for the details: An ngram tagger chooses a POS tag based on the current word and the `n-1` previous POS tags (the "context"). At the start of a sentence, a word has empty "context"; to tag the first word of your test phrase, the tagger needs to have seen it at the start of a sentence in your training data. 
The first word in your test phrase is `"that"`, without capitalization. Could it have really occurred in the training data? Yes it could:

```
>>> for n, s in enumerate(brown.sents(categories="news")):
        if s[0] == 'that':
            print(n, " ".join(s))

3322 that its persistent use by ballet companies of the Soviet regime indicates that that old spirit is just as stultifying alive today as it ever was ; ;
3323 that its presentation in this country is part of a capitalist plot to boobify the American people ; ;
3324 that its choreography is undistinguished and its score a shapeless assemblage of self-plagiarisms .
```

These are complete sentences, as far as the Brown corpus is concerned. There's probably a reason but it really doesn't matter, does it now. As long as your training data includes at least one of them, you'll be able to look up the context in the tagger's internal table:

```
>>> bigram_tager._context_to_tag[(tuple(), "that")]
'CS'
```

On the tagger you trained with the first 100 sentences (or on a tagger trained with the first 3000 sentences, since there's still no lowercase "that" in the right place), try the same thing and you'll get a `KeyError`. The context has not been seen, and the tagger returns `None` as the tag of the first word.
Once that has failed, tagging the second word will fail (wrong context again), etc.

Practical advice: Always use a backoff tagger (which will use all instances of a word to choose a tag), tag complete sentences with proper capitalization, or both.